# How to access function inside of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

today my question is asking how I would access a function inside a function. So, for example, I have a button, and if I click it, it would alert. The thing is, if you have a function surrounding the function, the inside function with the alert would not alert.

Here's an example:

html:

```
<button onclick="doStuff()">Alert</button>
```

js:

```
function nothing() {

var doStuff = function() {
    alert("This worked!")
}

}
```

so the `doStuff()` function would not work. Can someone help me find a way to access it?

Comment: Why does the function need to be inside another function?

Comment: You simply cannot. `doStuff` is visible only inside `nothing()`.

Comment: The code inside `nothing` (including `doStuff`) does not run until you call `nothing`. So you must call it. And then you can make `doStuff` available to the outside by returning it, or assigning it to a variable defined in another scope, etc. But I think you want `doStuff` to be a method of `nothing` instead of part of its inner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joseph the Dreamer is ultimately correct, but if you were dead set on calling a function that's nested in another function you could use an OOP approach.

Create a javascript "class" object and scope your function to "this":

```
function Nothing() {
    this.doStuff = function() {
        alert("works");
    }
}
```

- Next you add an id to your button,
- along with a click event listener

Then, inside your click event you can call doStuff within the Nothing "Class" function like this:

```
var object = new Nothing();
object.doStuff();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/me7fek5f/

Comment: Oh, I get it so your using object programming. That's something I could do. Thanks bro.

Comment: Yeah, so I was thinking to switch games using buttons

Comment: the button onclick activates a function

Comment: I haven't gotten all the other code on here but here's the website:

Comment: @SushiIsAwesome Your fiddle was empty, but heres some jQuery that can help you switch http://jsfiddle.net/c4gbkgaf/2/

Comment: oh really let me check again

Comment: delete the sushi123sushi mabye

Comment: It's tricky cuz i have lots of functions and does objects respond to buttons?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95001/discussion-between-dan-beaulieu-and-sushi-is-awesome).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's because it's enclosed in a scope that you can't really access globally. The only way you can access it is to expose it somewhere outside `nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework question?

You're probably asked to do something like this:

```
function nothing() {
  var doStuff = function() {
    alert("This worked!")
  }
  var yourButton = getYourButton();
  attachClickListener(yourButton, doStuff);
```

The implementations of getYourButton and attachClickListener are left to the reader.

Comment: No i was coding a game although i was trying to access a function inside a function